# GAS - sending email per sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I developped a script, sending a selected range from a Google sheet per email - it just works fine, if I use a dialogue box:

```
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(content);
    output.setHeight(500); 
    output.setWidth(700);    
    ui.showModalDialog(output,title);
```

But if I try to do this per sidebar, it does not work, the email will not be sent:

```
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(content)
  output.setTitle(title);
  ui.showSidebar(output);
```

Are there any restrictions for sidebars? And if yes - how do I get around this?

Comment: Do you see any execution errors when you view the logs?

Comment: There is no difference in what you can do with a sidebar versus a dialog box.